# $Z=X+Y$,when $X$ and $Y$ are gaussian distribution ,must $Z$ be the gaussian distribution,too?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be gaussian distribution,and $Z=X+Y$,must $Z$ be the gaussian distribution,too? my classmate said only when the covariance or correlation,I forgot,of $X$ and $Y$ be the same ,will the $Z$ be the gaussian too.

Can anyone correct me or give me some proof about it?

Comment: If they're independent, yes. Not independent? There's a bit more work.

Comment: Calling bs on this one, bot-generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $Z$ need not be Gaussian.  For example, let $X$ be Gaussian with mean zero and define $Y=-X$ if $|X|>1$ and $Y=X$ otherwise.  Then $Y$ is also Gaussian (check its cdf), but $X+Y$ is clearly not Gaussian since it has a point mass at $0$ without being identically equal to $0$, and it is supported on $[-2,2]$ (whereas if it were Gaussian its range would be the whole real line).

Comment: Z need not be Gaussian,this mean z can be gaussian,and can be not gaussian?or Z must not be gaussian?

Comment: Z can be Gaussian.  For example, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $Z$ will be Gaussian, and also (for example) if $X=Y$ then $Z$ will be Gaussian. And if $\{G_i\}$ are independent Gaussian and $X=\sum_i{a_iG_i}$ and $Y=\sum_i{b_iG_i}$ for constants $\{a_i\}\cup\{b_i\}$, then again $Z$ will be Gaussian.  But in general $Z$ will not be Gaussian.

Comment: Note in the previous comment the $G_i$ are intended to have mean zero.  (However, I'm pretty sure that if they don't, $X$ and $Y$ are never going to be Gaussian with mean zero anyway.)